# Is travel between Italy and the UK limitless with a Permesso di Soggiorno?

Tags: visas, uk, italy, permesso-di-soggiorno, residence-permits

I am a UK national and will be moving to work in Italy with a contract of 3 years during which I will receive a *Permesso di Soggiorno*

The current [National Visa (D) Form](https://conslondra.esteri.it/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/60400_f_cons57Application_national_visa.pdf) form has a field:

> 24. Number of entries required:
>
> [ ] One [ ] Two [ ] Multiple

Once I have been issued a *Permesso di Soggiorno* will it allow me limitless travel between the UK and Italy?

**OR**

Will I need to re-apply for a visa under the `Multiple` field to allow for limitless travel between the UK and Italy?

**Edit: Post Script**

In the end it took 9 months for our permesso to arrive. The only trouble we had in that time was when flying via another airport. We sadly could not always take direct flights back to the UK. In the situations we would have to transfer somewhere else in Europe there was usually a bit of confusion at passport control, in particular we had some trouble at Frankfurt. Italy is aware of its own system but that does not mean the rest of Europe is. This *can* be a problem if you have a tight transfer window, so keep it in mind when booking flights.

Comment: Your present permit allows you to reside in Italy. As a UK citizen, based on your passport alone, you can travel back and forth as often as you want, since you don't require a Schengen Visa to enter the Schengen Area.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number of entry on a D visa is meaningless in your case.

Because, you will receive a *Permesso di Soggiorno*, which is a common format residence permit, which allows you to enter/exit/transit/visit Schengen however you like (provided you respect the Schengen clock if you are looking to visit other Schengen states of course).

As a national D visa is only used for initial entry and then the residence permit takes the place of it proving your legal stay in the country

---

The little differing bit is when you apply for it because this can take months for you to receive the card.

Without the physical card, you would usually be required to apply again for a return visa abroad, before being able to return to the country. With the exception during a **renewal** when it is common rule to allow you to travel with the renewal application receipt and the expired permit

---

Italy is differing quite a bit in that sense because, contrary to most other Schengen countries, you can leave and re-enter freely while your first application for a *Permesso* is processed.

You need to provide to the border official the receipt that you receive from the Post Office when you lodge your initial application and must leave/re-enter the Schengen Area through Italy and not other Schengen states while you don't have your permesso

La [polizia del Stato](https://www.poliziadistato.it/articolo/10722) states :

> > The same facilitated procedure is granted to foreigners who have submitted their application for their **first** residence permits for
> > **employment, self-employment, or family reunification**, provided that:
>
> - they leave and re-enter Italy through any Italian external border crossing point (cicular letter 11th March 2009);
> - they show their passport or other equivalent travel document, along with the entry visa specifying the reasons of their stay (employment,
>   self-employment, or family reunification ) and the receipt issued by
>   Italian Post offices (Poste Italiane S.p.A.);
> - they do not transit through other Schengen countries, as this is not allowed.

Comment: _you would usually be required to apply again for a return visa_ even if I check `Multiple`? For instance, if I needed to travel back to the UK **_before_** I receive the Permesso di Soggiorno would selecting `Multiple` mean I could do so freely, or would I still need to apply for Re-entry to Italy?

Comment: The last part of the answer treat exactly your issue @fdcpp

Comment: If I have parsed that correctly I can exit  / re-enter Italy freely so long as I have at least some receipt of my Permesso di Soggiorno even if I have selected Single entry on my visa application form. Have I understood correctly?

Comment: @fdcpp Yes, as long as you fulfill the requirements set out by the Polizia del Stato, you are free to leave/re-enter Italy

Comment: Since the cost of a `Multiple` entry visa is greater than `Single` if the office submitting my application was pressuring me for `Multiple` entry and they were in full knowledge that I would be getting a Permesso di Soggiorno, would that suggest they were pressuring me unnecessarily.

Comment: @fdcpp It isn't more expensive, the cost for a D visa is the [same](https://visa.vfsglobal.com/one-pager/italy/uk/london/#Subordinate-work) irrespective of the numbers of entries, why would they pressure you? This is weird

Comment: I get the impression the agent did not know what they were doing. Being new to the process I thought it best to reschedule armed with a bit more information. The answer and links provide that, so thank you very much.

Comment: As a UK citizen, that **doesn't** require a Schengen Visa for the other Schengen countries, only some proof of residence is required to explain why the enter/exit stamps cannot be used to determine the amount of days spent in the other Schengen countries since the days in Italy don't count.