# Travel outside Italy with Schengen visa but no residence permit

Tags: schengen-visas, italy, long-stay-visas, permesso-di-soggiorno

I have a non-EU passport and a long-term D-visa for Italy. I have applied for my permesso di soggiorno and I only have the receipt with me. My visa is a multi-entry visa valid for 1 year. Will there be a problem while traveling to other Schengen countries and returning back to Italy?

Edit - I guess it would come down to if I will be required to show my residency permit while entering the next country or while entering back to Italy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is travel between Italy and the UK limitless with a Permesso di Soggiorno?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/178455/is-travel-between-italy-and-the-uk-limitless-with-a-permesso-di-soggiorno)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. The article attached to the post talks about transiting a schengen state on the way to and from Italy. Which would be mean one will have to go through immigration in that state. However I will be traveling directly between two schengen states without the need to go through immigration. I'm confused if the same rules apply.

Answer (score 2):

Update - I traveled to Sweden & back from Italy with only my passport, visa & my 1st permesso di soggiorno receipt.

Sweden had border control police who go through your documents making sure you're legitimate. They don't stamp the passports so it's technically not breaking schengen law.

The visa & receipt is adequate for travel within the Schengen area until the validity of the visa. Afterwards it's dependent on the permesso being renewed.